# Existence of solution for the modified heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I want to know if there exists any solution of the equation

$$\eqalign{
  & {u_t} =  - {u_{xx}}  \cr 
  & u(0,1) = u(0,\pi ) = 0  \cr 
  & u(0,x) = {u_0}(x) \cr} $$

We can easily obtain the solution of this equation by using variables separation method $$u(t,x) = \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 1} {{c_n}{e^{{n^2}t}}\sin (nx)} $$
but this solution is not defined for any $t>0$, the serie diverges.

I'm write? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your x-solution is correct.

Comment: This is the backwards heat equation, which in general does not have solutions (for example if $u_0$ is not analytic).